# Type 'Observable<User | null>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<User>'

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase-authentication, observable, angularfire

So here is the authService.ts :

````
 user$: Observable<firebase.User> 

 constructor(private afAuth: AngularFireAuth) { 
 this.user$ = afAuth.authState ;  //<-------- here's the problem
  }```
````

Comment: How can I fix this error: 
error TS2322: Type'Observable<User | 
Type 'User | null' is not assignable to type 'User'.
Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'User'.

Comment: You need to set the type of your observable as Observable<firebase.User|null> since it is how authstate is defined: https://github.com/angular/angularfire/blob/master/src/auth/auth.ts#L40

Answer (score 2):

It depends on your intention, do you want to allow `null`?

If so, just change the typing on your `user$`:

```
 user$: Observable<firebase.User|null>
```

If you don't want null, you could filter out null emissions:

```
this.user$ = afAuth.authState.pipe(
   filter(u => !!u)
)
```

Comment: After implementing the second method I have this error now :

Error: src/app/auth.service.ts:18:19 - error TS2769: No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 2, '(predicate: (value: User | null, index: number) => value is User, thisArg?: any): OperatorFunction<User | null, User>', gave the following error.
    Type 'User | null' is not assignable to type 'boolean'.
      Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'boolean'.

Comment: Overload 2 of 2, '(predicate: (value: User | null, index: number) => boolean, thisArg?: any): MonoTypeOperatorFunction<User | null>', gave the following error.
    Type 'User | null' is not assignable to type 'boolean'.
      Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'boolean'.

18       filter(u => u)

Comment: does it work if you do: `filter(u => !!u)`

Answer (score 1):

I am using vanilla script so I had to made custom observable to achieve that

```
 this.userob=new Observable(observe=>{
auth.onAuthStateChanged(x=>{                          
  observe.next(x);
})
```

})

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31241837)

Answer (score 0):

I solved this as below

1. First I add `.map<firebase.User>()`
2. then I add `<firebase.User | null>`

This gave me error on `.map` method in VS Code but on `this.user$ = afAuth.authState;` error was removed.

So I saved file and removed `.map`.